# Just upgraded to latest Ubuntu 22.04 and I lost all mouse controls. what should I try to get windows to work again?

Tags: gnome, upgrade, virtualbox, mouse

This morning I upgraded a VirtualBox Ubuntu 22.04 installation running Gnome.

After the update, I got a new kernel so I decided to reboot.

Since then, the mouse doesn't work on any of the Windows decoration (buttons in the title bar, scrollbar) or the Gnome environment, except the icons used to open apps. (so the top-right preference menu, and top-left Activities are all dead).

Any reason why that would happen? Something I can try to fix the issue?

The Host is an Ubuntu 18.04 server which works just fine at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just Rebooting, I tried to shutdown (`sudo init 0` in my console) and then restarted from scratch.

That fixed the issue.

A simple reboot (`sudo init 6`) must have had some old *something or other* in memory which was not dealt with properly. I usually don't have to fully shutdown and restart so I did not think of it immediately.